# Show centered menu on recycler view item click

Tags: android, user-interface, popup

I have a `RecyclerView` and I'm showing a menu on item click (in my case it's a delete action). I'm using `PopupMenu`, it works fine, but shows my menu action aligned either view end or start. Tried to set  menu gravity while defining it

```
PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(getContext(), view, Gravity.CENTER);
```

How can I set my popup menu in center. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is no functionality by default.Think you would need implement your own classes of PopupMenu and MenuPopupHelper